# How do I duplicate column data and preserve row relationships across worksheets?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013, sorting

I have a large amount of data on one worksheet, and would like to split it between two separate linked worksheets.

Assume I have these columns on my first worksheet (Worksheet A):

```
Apple   | Red
Banana  | Yellow
Lime    | Green
```

I would like to connect that first column to a column on my second worksheet (Worksheet B), so that I can enter data applying to the member data in the first column.

```
Apple [Linked]    | $.25
Banana [Linked]   | $1.00
Lime  [Linked]    | $1.50
```

Simply linking the cells using a "=#cellAddress" formula or Paste Special > Paste Link does not fulfill my needs; if either of the first columns are sorted, the data in the second column on the opposing worksheet does not move in kind.

For example, if you attempt to sort the first column of Worksheet A alphabetically....

```
Lime    | Green
Banana  | Yellow
Apple   | Red
```

, Worksheet B will still have...

```
Lime  [Linked]    | $.25
Banana [Linked]   | $1.00
Apple [Linked]    | $1.50
```

The data I am using is also added to and changes regularly, so simply copying and pasting the column from Worksheet A to Worksheet B does not fulfill my needs either; the data needs to update in real time.

I've tried both formulas and setting up relationship tables, but nothing lets me keep my row data straight across the worksheets.

I've tried Table Relationships, simply copying the values from the Worksheet A headers and typing in my Worksheet B data, then creating a table for both and setting up a relationship. This does not allow for updating the column data, though- attempting to add a "Pears" row or renaming "Apple" to "Green Apple" does not propagate from Worksheet A to Worksheet B.

I need some way of sharing this column data across both Worksheets while still preserving the independence of each worksheet's row data (through tables, probably).

I've been working on this for a few days and I'm not sure what else I can even try at this point.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to **look up** the value *after* it sorts with something like:

```
=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(MATCH("Apple",A:A,0),1))
```

I wouldn't use `Indirect` though, this is better:

```
=INDEX(Sheet2!$A$1:$A$4,MATCH("Apple",Sheet2!$A$1:$A$4,0))
```

To get cells in reference to that cell, you will need:

```
=OFFSET(INDEX(Sheet2!$A$1:$A$4,MATCH("Apple",Sheet2!$A$1:$A$4,0)),,1)
```

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what you're intending here. Referring back to my example, I inserted your formula into the Worksheet B, Column B, and made to reference the value in Column A (which is taken from Worksheet A.)


My Worksheet B formulas are now


=Sheet1!A1  |  =OFFSET(INDEX(Sheet1!$A$1:$A$4,MATCH(A1,Sheet1!$A$1:$A$4,0)),,1)


with an output of 


Apple  |  Red


Could you please give an example of what the output of your formula should resemble?

Comment: Use the second formula on worksheet B, replacing Sheet2 with worksheet A

Comment: Right, which makes my Worksheet B formulas =Sheet1!A1 | =OFFSET(INDEX(Sheet1!$A$1:$A$4,MATCH(A1,Sheet1!$A$1:$A$4,0))‌​,,1) with an output of Apple | Red

Comment: You would get that, but if you sort anything on sheet1 it will remain correct on sheet B. If you change the "apple" to "green apple" it won't know that.

Comment: It actually does, though, since the cell address in MATCH links it to the data in the first sheet, but whatever. This doesn't really address the primary problem of the data in Worksheet 2, Column 2 mixing the rows when data in the first sheet is sorted.

Comment: What is the question then? You have data on one sheet and you want a master column on a second sheet that knows what row its value is on in the first sheet - the index does that. Whatever you do on the first sheet, the second sheet still knows where its value is. Then you offset, or vlookup or whatever in reference to the value on the second sheet to retrieve corresponding data from the first sheet. Am I understanding correctly?

Comment: No. You might want to reread the question in the OP

Comment: That's how I read it, still.